# Where can I find a screensaver that makes the screen go blurry?

Tags: screensaver

Most screen screen saver sites seem to be filled with spyware. Where can I find a screensaver that makes the screen blur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Focus Screensaver**](http://gv91.deviantart.com/art/Focus-Screensaver-102592139) is nice but doesn't support multiple monitors.

[image]

Comment: too bad it's a dead link :(

Comment: It's an old thread but looks like it's the same screensaver that can be downloaded [here](https://www.screensaversplanet.com/screensavers/out-of-focus-1390/). It does not support multiple displays and also does not pair well with any system scale but 100%, so you'll get a cropped top left quarter of a screen if you have a 4k display with 200% scale for example.

Answer (score 2):

- [Blur](http://www.screensaver-network.com/savers/content/USContent0009.html) from Screensaver-Network
- <strike>[Blur Screensaver](http://wareseeker.com/download/blur-screen-saver-1.0.1.0.rar/51405)</strike> - no longer exists